# VBA Excel loop based on a cell value

Tags: excel, vba

I am working on a project, I started it in google-apps-script, the client wants it in Excel since he is satisfied, but having difficulty porting over the code as VBA is not the language I am most familiar with.

The functionality that I am trying to get control over is to loop again based on a value.

```
Sub readDataWriteToNewSheet()

Debug.Print "Starting....."

Sheet5.Cells(1, 1).CurrentRegion.ClearContents

myArray = Sheet3.Cells(1, 1).CurrentRegion

For rw = 1 To UBound(myArray)
    
    paymentsToMake = myArray(rw, 7)
    
    If paymentsToMake > 1 Then
        
        For i = 1 To paymentsToMake
            Debug.Print "Hello"
        Next

    End If
Next
End Sub
```

What I have tried so far is to make another variable, for example:

```
temp = CInt(myArray(rw, 7))
```

I have also tried

```
temp = myArray(rw, 7)
```

I get a type mismatch error

Comment: myArray is a Range so it is an object, not an array as you might have assumed from its name.

Comment: how can I get the value of the cell paymentsToMake = myArray(rw, 7) to make another for next loop?

Comment: A good start - turn on `Option Explicit` and declare your variables.  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/option-explicit-statement

Answer (score 0):

Try to play on this.

```
Sub readDataWriteToNewSheet()
Dim myArray As Range

Debug.Print "Starting....."

Sheet5.Cells(1, 1).CurrentRegion.ClearContents

' myArray variable is inappropriately named but it will do as long as it is treated like a range
Set myArray = Sheet3.Cells(1, 1).CurrentRegion

' removed the Ubound which is for array, my bad
For rw = 1 To myArray.Rows.Count
    ' how to take the value from a cell
    paymentsToMake = Sheet3.Cells(rw, 7).Value
    
    If paymentsToMake > 1 Then
        
        For i = 1 To paymentsToMake
            Debug.Print "Hello"
        Next

    End If
Next
End Sub
```

Comment: Getting a compile error, "Expected array"

Comment: I am sorry about that.  I did not test it on Excel. I took out the Ubound which causing the error. I tested this. Please try again.

Comment: Now getting the old error, type mismatch, it is on line where For i =1 To PaymentsToMake

Comment: what is the value of paymentsToMake? You may debug the values by pressing F8 every step. Hover over the variables or you may use Locals Windows. (To show it, go to View, Local Windows).

Comment: Found the solution, I was trying to iterate the whole sheet, the header column is what caused the problems as it is text but that column data is an integer. That is something I will have to tackle later, but starting from row 2 seems to got it to work.

Comment: Congratulations!

Comment: Replace "For rw = 1" with "For rw = 2" to skip the header.

Answer (score 0):

I was in two minds as to whether to post this or not. There's nothing wrong with @Wils Mils answer at all, but it is taking a slightly different approach to that which you intended (I believe). For that reason, I'm offering this answer as an alternative for completeness.

**There's very little wrong with your original code.** Copying the data into an array allows for *much* faster testing of the range's contents than accessing each cell directly. But there were 2 issues that prevented it from working as you'd hoped.

1. You were creating a Range object instead of an actual array for myArray.
2. If you are using an *2* dimensional array (created when 'copied' from a range) then `Ubound` needs to know *which* dimension you're interested in.

The following code should work - I've left your code as comments in situ so you can see what has changed:

```
Sub readDataWriteToNewSheet()

    Debug.Print "Starting....."
    
    Sheet5.Cells(1, 1).CurrentRegion.ClearContents
    
    'myArray = Sheet3.Cells(1, 1).CurrentRegion    - original code
    myarray = Sheet3.Cells(1, 1).CurrentRegion.Value
    
    'For rw = 1 To UBound(myArray)    - original code
    For rw = 2 To UBound(myarray, 1)
        
        paymentsToMake = myarray(rw, 7)
        
        If paymentsToMake > 1 Then
            
            For i = 1 To paymentsToMake
                Debug.Print "Hello"
            Next
    
        End If
    Next
    
End Sub
```

You should also declare your variables with `Dim` statements if we're being thorough.

Answer (score 0):

### Values (No Headers) of (Table) Column to Array

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub ReadDataWriteToNewSheet()
    
    Const sCol As Long = 7

    Dim srg As Range: Set srg = Sheet3.Cells(1).CurrentRegion
    If srg.Columns.Count < sCol Then Exit Sub ' too few columns
    Dim srCount As Long: srCount = srg.Rows.Count - 1
    If srCount = 0 Then Exit Sub ' only one row i.e. only headers
    
    ' Write only the values (no headers) of column 'sCol' to Source Array.
    Dim sData As Variant
    If srCount = 1 Then ' one cell (row) only
        ReDim sData(1 To 1, 1 To 1): sData = srg.Cells(2, sCol).Value
    Else
        sData = srg.Columns(sCol).Resize(srCount).Offset(1).Value
    End If
    
    Dim Payments As Variant
    Dim r As Long
    Dim n As Long
    For r = 1 To srCount
        Payments = sData(r, 1)
        If IsNumeric(Payments) Then
            If Payments > 1 Then
                For n = 1 To Payments
                    Debug.Print r, n & "(" & Payments & ")", "Hello"
                Next n
            End If
        End If
    Next r
    
End Sub
```